# Cannot set constraints for image view

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, constraints

First I'd like to stress that I've spent quite some time looking for an ansswer and maybe I haven't found one simply because I'm not really understanding how it's working.
I'm setting up a UI, but can't manage to move an imageview by modifying its constraints. Basically my problem is that modifying constraints doesn't seem to modify the image's position.

Here's my layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="geoensea.ensea.com.geoensea.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="41dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="60dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/button_send"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/imageView"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="326dp"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/map_rdc"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_two_men"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.541" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="165dp"
        android:layout_height="74dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="@string/title"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

my main activity

```
    package geoensea.ensea.com.geoensea;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Gallery;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //Image

            // Create a LinearLayout in which to add the ImageView
            mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(this);

            // Instantiate an ImageView and define its properties
            ImageView i = new ImageView(this);
            i.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_two_men);

            // set the ImageView bounds to match the Drawable's dimensions
            i.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
            i.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // Add the ImageView to the layout and set the layout as the content view
            mLinearLayout.addView(i);
            setContentView(mLinearLayout);

        //Button new activity

    }
}
```

The image is always in the left top corner of the layout:

[Here is an image of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QaenU.png)

Comment: Please be specific and provide some details. What is the problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't actually said what is the problem but I see that your ImageView has horizontal bias declared. It wont work without start and end constraint specified.

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="326dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/map_rdc"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_two_men"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5" />
```

To clarify this code: You've specified start and end constraint for your view and also set it's width to given value. In such situation there are side margins (between scren edge and edge of your view). Android has to calculate them and it's doing this using vertical bias parameter (dafault set to 0.5). Horizontal bias is just ratio of left and right margin (0.5: margins are equal, 0: left margin is equal to 0, 1: right margin is equal to 0).

EDIT:

What did you want to get using this code in your onCreate method? Just do simple:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ID_OF_THE_XML_YOU'VE_PASTED);
}
```

Do you know that you didnt actually use your xml file? Everything you've seen on the screen was generated dynamically in your onCreate method!

Just to be 100% sure you understand everything. Your xml file (this one we've been discussing all the time) has it's name... eg activity_main.xml. In such case type:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
```

Comment: My problem is that no matter what i do on the constraints, the image never moves, it's always in the top left corner.

Comment: I extended the code in my answer. Please try it. It just has to work.

Comment: It doesn't work, may be it's due to my main activity code ? I'm using a linear Layout instance.

Comment: Done. I've added as well an image of what is exactly my problem.

Comment: It works much much better thank you. As for the code I have in the main activity it's just the code that is on this link : https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/drawables.html